# Get previous li of active class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following html

```
<ul>
   <li>Home</li>
   <li class="active">About</li>
   <li>Contact</li>
</ul>
```

I want to override some css property of a li only if the next li class is active.

My css is

```
ul li{
color:#eee
}

ul li.active{
color:#000;
}
```

So I want to add a border to that li whose next li class is active.So in this case I want to add a border to home.It can't be same all the time as if the active class is set for contact then I would like to add a border for about us.

I am not sure if this can be done using css or javascript.

Any suggestion/hint is highly welcomed. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `$('ul .active').removeClass('active').prev().addClass('active');` -- http://jsfiddle.net/Lqz3aye0/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using JavaScript:

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chipChocolate/n0f4f84u/1/)

```
// get all li elements
var li = document.getElementsByTagName('li');

// loop through all li elements
for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {

    // if the first element's class list contains 'active'
    if (i == 0 && li[i].classList.contains('active')) {
        // change css properties of the last element
        li[li.length - 1].style.borderWidth = '1px';
        li[li.length - 1].style.borderColor = 'red';
        li[li.length - 1].style.borderStyle = 'solid';
    }

    // check if next li element's class list contains 'active'
    if (li[i + 1].classList.contains('active')) {
        // add border to the current li element
        li[i].style.borderWidth = '1px';
        li[i].style.borderColor = 'red';
        li[i].style.borderStyle = 'solid';
    }
}
```

### When the first `li` element has `active` class -----> [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chipChocolate/n0f4f84u/4/)

Comment: Many thanks for your help.I changed this line var li = document.getElementsByTagName('li'); to var li = document.getElementsByTagName('top_menu ul li'); Is it possible?

Comment: No for that you will have to use `document.querySelector('top_menu ul li')`

Comment: @Raj - `document.getElementsByTagName(tagname)` only lets you select an element with a tag name.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it with css, you have to use JavaScript or jQuery.

With jQuery you ca do like this:

```
$("li.active").prev().addClass("prev");
$("li").on("click", function(){
   $("li").removeClass("active").prev().removeClass("prev");
   $(this).addClass("active").prev().addClass("prev");
});
```

<kbd>[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z1bgujj6/)</kbd>